# My function does not return anything no matter what I try

Tags: python, function, return

```
def iq_test(numbers):
    i = 0
    length = len(numbers)
    numbers = numbers.split()
    ints = []
    even = []
    odd = []
    try:
        for i in range(i, length, i + 1):
            number = int(numbers[i])
            ints.append(number)
            if ints[i] % 2 == 0:
                even.append(ints[i])
            else:
                odd.append(ints[i])



    except:
        pass
    if len(even) > len(odd):
        return i
    else:
       return i

iq_test("1 2 2")
```

No matter how many times or ways I try to fix this it doesn't seem to return `i`. Whenever I do `print(i)` it gives me the exact thing I wanted and the function works well, but when it's `return i` I get nothing, how can I fix this?
Edit: this function is supposed to take in some numbers (in string format), one of those numbers will be different in evenness (one is even and the rest are odd and vice versa), I want to return the index of that number.

Comment: I can see indentation errors. Please fix them. Also, you need to print the values, ```print(iq_test("1 2 2"))```. Right now, it is just returning the value. You aren't using them

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish? We cannot identify errors in code if we don't know what it is supposed to be doing

Comment: You should always put something in your except block. Otherwise you can have errors and get no feedback. If you at least printed the error you would see: `list index out of range` and would not need to ask here. `Except: pass` is *almost* always wrong.

Comment: While I don't really know what you're trying to achieve, it appears that the line: 
length = len(numbers) should go after the line: numbers = numbers.split()

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for i in range(len(list)):`. it's almost always more appropriate to use `for item in list:`

Comment: Returning something is not the same as printing it. Please redo a tutorial on functions. `x = iq_test(...)` puts the return value in the variable `x`. You can then `print(x)` to print its value

Comment: I know that printing something is not the same as returning it. I can print the value that I need just fine, but returning it doesn't work (and I need it to be returned, rather than printed).

Comment: How does your code verify that nothing is returned? I don't see any test..

Comment: @Killah4Ever if you're expecting the line `iq_test("1 2 2")` to print the result of that function call, it won't do so (unless you're running this in a REPL). You need to do `x = iq_test("1 2 2")` and then `print(x)`, or simply `print(iq_test("1 2 2"))`

Comment: [proof of return](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions68548896my-function-doe). I vote to close this question as not reproducible.

Comment: @Killah4Ever: You must be clear about what you want. Your title says that your function does not return anything, which is obviously not true. Then later you say that your function does not return `i`. Again obviously not true. Later again you say that you want to return the index of one of the numbers, but you never store the indexes of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code and it's working :

```
def iq_test(numbers):
     i = 0
     numbers = list(map(int,numbers.split()))
     even = []
     odd = []
     try:
         for i in range(len(numbers)):
            if numbers[i] % 2 == 0:
               even.append(i)
            else:
               odd.append(i)
     except:
         pass
     finally:
         if len(even) > len(odd):
            return odd[0]
         else:
            return even[0]
print(iq_test("1 1 2"))
```

Points I have modified :

- instead of creating another list for converting list elements to an integer you could just use the `map function`
- you should store the index of the even and odd value instead of the value itself
- And if there is something in the code that is necessary to do even if the error occurs you could use the `finally block`

Comment: @quamrana thanks for pointing that, I forgot to remove it  as it won't be necessary now

Answer (score 0):

```
def iq_test(numbers):
        numbers = numbers.split()
        length = len(numbers)
        ints = []
        even = []
        odd = []
        try:
            for i in range(0, length):
                number = int(numbers[i])
                ints.append(number)
                if ints[i] % 2 == 0:
                    even.append(ints[i])
                else:
                    odd.append(ints[i])
            if len(even) > len(odd):
                return even[0]
            else:
                return odd[0]
        except:
            pass
        
    ReturnedNumber = iq_test("1 2 2")
    print("Returned number from function:",ReturnedNumber)
```